# Android: How to create a loading bar with text half one colour and half another

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to create a bar chart/ loading bar where the text is half one colour and half one another and have been struggling to come up with a simple way to tackle this. My ideas thus far have revolved around creating both bars in their complete state and then having a pair of 'selective transparency' views which would show the respective halves to create the effect.

I've been unable to find how to do this selective transparency/ opacity view. Is this possible? Is there some other blindingly obvious way to achieve this effect?

Here's a quick drawing of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I don't know android, but clipping might also be a possibility - https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to implement it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this, I managed to solve this by using [setClipBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClipBounds(android.graphics.Rect)). I did it by creating two textviews of the full size, one with a coloured number and transparent background and the second with a white number and coloured background. Then setClipBounds is applied to the coloured textview as follows -

```
textview.setClipBounds( new Rect(0, originalHeight*(1 - progress), originalWidth, originalHeight);
```

Here, the variable `progress` has a value between 0 and 1. The Rect has to be defined relative to the view, not relative to the screen.
This exact setup achieves an effect something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGN0O.png), but it could easily be changed to a horizontal bar or whatever else is required.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow misinterpreted the question. The best way to achieve this would be to create the images and set as background to an imageview instead of a textview.

Comment: Not entirely sure if I follow. Do you mean generate a drawable (or something like that) for each half and then display it in an imageview then setting the dimensions of each imageview accordingly?

Comment: Use photoshop, create an image of what you want to display, set that image as the imageview drawable.

Comment: Sorry, probably didn't make it clear. The number has to change to display progress, so I could do that but I'd rather not have 100 images to display in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a [LinearGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html) 
With the parameters colors and positions you can indicate the loading progress.
You can use the gradient when you override the onDraw [Custom Drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)